# Cut the SUBSTRINGS to a specific length in a CSV file

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a file like below,
cat `Test.csv`

```
"pav",12345,"ABCD,EF;xyz23;15rtg",,
"xyz",,"C4DEF;x23yu;rtg",,
```

After modification :

```
cat Test.csv

"pav",12345,"AB;xy;15",,
"xyz",,"C4;x2;rt",,
```

The **3**rd field containing substrings delimited with "`;`" has to be replaced with their substrings

Comment: Only 5 columns ?and only third column should be replaced?or it's can appear in different columns too?

Comment: @αғsнιη The data has 5 columns, with the 4th and 5th being empty, it seems.

Comment: ah, yes, edited my comment

Answer (score 0):

Complex GNU **`AWK`** solution (parsing `csv` data):

```
awk -v FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^",]+|,,' '{ 
           for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { 
               if ($i~/^".*;./) { 
                   len=split($i,a,";"); v=substr(a[1],1,3); 
                   for (j=2;j<=len;j++) v= v";"substr(a[j],1,2);
                   v=v"\042"
               }  printf "%s%s",(v? v: ($i~/^,,/? (i==NF? ",":""):$i )),
                                (i==NF? ORS:OFS); v="" 
           } 
       }' OFS=',' Test.csv
```

- `FPAT='"[^"]+"|[^",]+|,,'` - complex regex pattern defining field value
- `if ($i~/^".*;./) ...` - if the current field `$i` contains `;` character(s)
- `len=split($i,a,";")` - split the field value `$i` into array `a` by separator `;`. `len` is assigned with number of elements/chunks created
- `v=substr(a[1],1,3);` - capturing the first chunk of the needed length including leading `"` char, for ex. `"AB` will be extracted from `"ABCD,EF`
- `for (j=2;j<=len;j++) ...` - iterating through remaining chunks/items
- `v=v"\042"` - add trailing double quote `"` to the processed sequence `v`. `\043` is ASCII octal code representing the double quote char `"`.
- `($i~/^,,/? (i==NF? ",":""):$i )` - each empty field `,,` is recreated with single comma `,` and common delimiter (also `,`). This is to avoid redundant comma cluttering like `"pav",,,`
- `(i==NF? ORS:OFS)` - on encountering the last field `i==NF` - print output record separator `ORS`, otherwise - print output filed separator `OFS`

---

The output:

```
"pav",12345,"AB;xy;15",,
"xyz",,"C4;x2;rt",,
```

Comment: Thanks Roman, Works perfect.  Could you help me in understanding bit better,  like  the 042 and arrays look bit complex.

Comment: @Pavan, welcome, see my explanation

Answer (score 0):

The following is using [`csvkit`](http://csvkit.readthedocs.io/), because parsing CSV data that contains commas in quoted fields with `awk` directly is error prone.

This will get column three on the correct format:

```
csvcut -c 3 file.csv |
sed -r 's/^"|"$//g' |
awk -F';' -vOFS=';' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) $i = substr($i, 0, 2) } { printf("\"%s\"\n", $0) }' >tmp-3rd
```

For the given input, this produces

```
"AB;xy;15"
"C4;x2;rt"
```

- `csvcut` will cut out the third column.
- `sed` will remove any double quotes from the data, if they appear first or last on the line.
- The `awk` program will go through the `;`-delimited fields and cut them down to a length of two characters per field. It prints out the data with double quotes around it.
- The output is written to the file `tmp-3rd`.

Then it's just a matter of reassembling this with the original data (this is assuming `bash` or any other shell that can do process substitutions with `<(...)`):

```
paste -d, <( csvcut -c 1,2 file.csv ) tmp-3rd <( csvcut -c 4,5 file.csv ) | csvformat
```

- `paste` will put the columns together with commas in-between.
- The first process substitution produces the first two columns from the original file, and the second produces the last two columns.  In the middle, we provide the modified third column.
- As an optional step, we pass the data through `csvformat` which will quote or unquote fields as needed.

The output will be

```
pav,12345,AB;xy;15,,
xyz,,C4;x2;rt,,
```

---

Bypassing the need for the temporary file:

```
paste -d, \
    <( csvcut -c 1,2 file.csv ) \
    <( csvcut -c 3 file.csv | sed -r 's/^"|"$//g' |
       awk -F';' -vOFS=';' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) $i = substr($i, 0, 2) } { printf("\"%s\"\n", $0) }' ) \
    <( csvcut -c 4,5 file.csv ) | csvformat
```

Comment: I doesn't seem to have a csvkit , will try to use thae AWK as the rest had concquered some how,   Thanks :)

Comment: @Pavan `pip install --user csvkit` will install the commands in `$HOME/.local/bin`.

Comment: I tried with  this which works fine  , but what i actually wasnt to is, the third field in above example has to be replaced with the modified one in he file could you help me :      awk -F',"' '{print $5 "\t" }' test.csv|awk -F';' -vOFS=';' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) $i = substr($i, 0, 25) }{ printf("\"%s\"\n", $0) }'

Comment: @Pavan I don't understand. Please update the question with the appropriate information.

Comment: I mean now i am able to see the output on the screen as expected,  But my actual need is to replace that in the actual file.                                                      awk -F',"' '{print $3 "\t" }' test.csv  --> helping me to print the 3rd field eg. "ABCD,EF;xyz23;15rtg"     and awk -F';' -vOFS=';' '{ for (i=1; i<=NF; ++i) $i = substr($i, 0, 2) }{ printf("\"%s\"\n", $0) }' --> helping me to limit the substrings to 2 char. the desired output is seen on the screen, but i want that to be updated in the file  and the file wold have like 50k lines and the action should happen to all lines

Comment: @Pavan Reading unformatted shell code in comments is impossible, so I will ignore that. Redirect the result of the command to a new file by placing `>newfilename` after the command. Then either continue working on the new file or, if you can verify that it looks correct, replace the old file with the new file.

Answer (score 0):

With `perl`

Assuming `;` is only in third field

```
$ perl -pe 's/"\K[^;"]*;[^"]*(?=")/$&=~s|([^;]{2})[^;]+|$1|gr/e' ip.txt
"pav",12345,"AB;xy;15",,
"xyz",,"C4;x2;rt",,
```

- `"\K` to match `"` before string of interest and `(?=")` to match `"` after string of interest. But the `"` themselves not part of captured string as these are lookarounds
- `[^;"]*;[^"]*` match any non `;` or `"` characters followed by `;` followed by non `"` characters
- `$&=~s|([^;]{2})[^;]+|$1|gr` to perform another substitution on the matched string
- `e` modifier allows to use Perl code in substitution section

To restrict only for 3rd field

```
$ cat ip.txt 
"pav",12345,"ABCD,EF;xyz23;15rtg",,
"xyz",,"C4DEF;x23yu;rtg",,
"foo;12,23;good",124,253
12,5232,"xyz","ijk;5545;62"

$ perl -pe 's/^("[^"]*",|[^,]*,){2}"\K[^;"]*;[^"]*(?=")/$&=~s|([^;]{2})[^;]+|$1|gr/e' ip.txt
"pav",12345,"AB;xy;15",,
"xyz",,"C4;x2;rt",,
"foo;12,23;good",124,253
12,5232,"xyz","ijk;5545;62"
```

Answer (score 0):

Accurate and robust ***Python*** 3.x solution (based on [***csv.reader***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html?highlight=csv#csv.reader) object):

`parse_csv.py` script:

```
import csv, sys
with open(sys.argv[1]) as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for l in reader:
        l = [s if ';' not in s else ';'.join(_[:2] for _ in s.split(';')) for s in l]
        print(','.join(i if not i or i.isnumeric() else '"{}"'.format(i) for i in l))
```

---

Usage:

```
python3 parse_csv.py Test.csv
```

The output:

```
"pav",12345,"AB;xy;15",,
"xyz",,"C4;x2;rt",,
```

---

Python's `csv` module provides robust and flexible support for `csv` data.